# Web wocket server python with socket module

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

**Problem:**

I am trying to make a backend web framework as a challenge and I'm trying to implement web
sockets but whenever I make the handshake my browser says that it received no response and the status is 'finished'.

[image: img os client code + console]

**Things I have tried:**

I have tried making the request to my own server using the requests module and same Sec Websocket Key as on another website and the key was the same as that other websites response.

I have also tried running it on a node.js server with the same code for the client and the whole thing worked as expected so it's a serverside problem.

Changing browsers and updating browser versions.

Changing from localhost to my private IP and my local machine name.

**code**

```py
# Ignore missing stuff, some stuff is missing to reduce the length and shouldn't be needed to debug

@app.route('/')
def ws(request: dict):
    if request.get('Connection') == 'Upgrade' and request.get('Upgrade') == 'websocket':
        # Get returns None if key doesn't exist [] raises keyerror

        print(f"Sec-Websocket-Key: {request['Sec-WebSocket-Key']}")
        # Prints correct key (:

        request['Sec-WebSocket-Key'] += '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11'
        SecWebSocketAccept = hashlib.sha1(request['Sec-WebSocket-Key'].encode())
        SecWebSocketAccept = SecWebSocketAccept.digest()
        SecWebSocketAccept = base64.b64encode(SecWebSocketAccept).decode()
        return HttpResponse(status_code=101,
                            message='Switching Protocols',
                            headers= {
                                'Upgrade': 'websocket',
                                'Connection': 'Upgrade',
                                'Sec-WebSocket-Accept': SecWebSocketAccept,
                                'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol': 'chat'
                            }, AutoGenerateExtraHeaders=False)
    else: 
        return RenderTemplate('example.html', minimize=False) 
        # warning: remove minimize only for testing

# HttpResponse class

class HttpResponse:
    def __init__(
        self,
        data: str = '', 
        status_code: int = 200, 
        message: str = 'OK', 
        headers: dict = {}, 
        AutoGenerateExtraHeaders=True
    )-> None:
        """ todo: add docs on class and methods"""
        self.protocol = 'HTTP/1.1'
        self.status = f'{status_code} {message}'
        self.data = data
        self.headers = headers
        if AutoGenerateExtraHeaders:
            contentmd5 = hashlib.md5(data.encode()).digest()
            self.headers['Content-MD5'] = base64.b64encode(contentmd5)
            self.headers['Content-Length'] = len(data.encode())
            # todo: add more headers such as date, 
        self.headers = str(headers)[2:].replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace(', \'', '\r\n\'').replace('\'', '')
        # String version of headers
    def encode(self) -> bytes:
        return str(self).encode()

# Handle Connection Code

def handleConnection(self, connection: socket.socket, address) -> None:
        """handles incoming requests

        Args:
            connection (socket.socket): client socket connection
            address: address of incoming connection
        """
        request = connection.recv(1024).decode()
        # print(request)
        if not request: return
        request: dict = self.dictFromRequest(request)
        route = self.app.getRoute(request['route']) # returns route object which is made up of a function and a URL defined by app.route(route: str) decor
        method: str = request['method']
        protocol: str = request['protocol']
        
        # 404 Page not found
        
        # Call event
        event = self.app.callEvent(RequestEvent(request))
        if event.timeOut: return
        
        # Handle
        if protocol == 'HTTP':
            # todo: cors and csrf
            if method == 'GET':
                response = route.call(request)
                print(f'encoded: {response.encode()}, \n\ndecoded: {response}') 
                # ouupt: 
                # encoded: b'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade: 
                # websocket\r\nConnection: 
                # Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: TwmkkaET4SyBJad/5OzZNHxaZ/o=\r\nSec
                # -WebSocket-Protocol: 
                # chat\r\n\r\n',
                #
                # decoded: HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
                # Upgrade: websocket
                # Connection: Upgrade
                # Sec-WebSocket-Accept: TwmkkaET4SyBJad/5OzZNHxaZ/o=
                # Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
                #
                #
                connection.send(response.encode())
                
        
        return connection.close()
            
    def dictFromRequest(self, headers: str) -> dict:
        # todo: just lol
        dict = {}
        dict['method'] = headers.split('\r\n\r\n')[0].split('\r\n')[0].split(' ')[0]
        dict['protocol'] = headers.split('\r\n')[0].split(' ')[-1].split('/')[0]
        dict['route'] = headers.split('\r\n\r\n')[0].split('\r\n')[0].split(' ')[1].split('?')[0]
        dict['query'] = ''.join(headers.split('\n\n')[0].split('\r\n')[0].split(' ')[1].split('?')[1:])
        dict['data'] = headers.split('\r\n\r\n')[1]
        for header in headers.split('\r\n\r\n')[0].split('\r\n')[1:]:
            dict[header.split(': ')[0]] = header.split(': ')[1]
        return dict
```

P.S. pls don't judge I'm only 13 lol

Comment: don't you get error message when you run Python code in console? How do you run Python code? What IP do you use in Python?

Comment: you could at least crop image. But better always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: @furas no i I don't get any errors in the python console